# DateTime sum returns TypeError: not an integer on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I need to sum an array of datetimes for caching expiration purposes, such as

```
# posts_controller.rb
@posts = Post.all

# index.html.erb
<% cache [:posts, :index, @posts.sum(&:updated_at)] do %>
# ...
```

Which I think would be equal to:

```
@posts.map(&:updated_at).reduce(:+)
```

The problem is that the code is working properly locally (cache on and console-tested) but returning the following error on production when I deploy to heroku:

```
TypeError: not an integer
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:67:in `convert'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:67:in `Rational'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:67:in `since'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:116:in `rescue in since'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:114:in `since'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:223:in `rescue in +'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:223:in `+'
from (irb):25:in `each'
from (irb):25:in `reduce'
from (irb):25
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Ruby version is the same (1.9.3). Rails version is the same (3.2.13).

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

```
@posts.map(&:updated_at)
```

contains

```
[Thu, 11 Jul 2013 18:35:53 UTC +00:00, Thu, 11 Jul 2013 18:35:58 UTC +00:00,
Thu,11 Jul 2013 18:36:02 UTC +00:00, Thu, 11 Jul 2013 18:36:05 UTC +00:00,
Thu, 11 Jul 2013 18:36:09 UTC +00:00, Thu, 11 Jul 2013 18:36:14 UTC +00:00,
Thu, 11 Jul 2013 18:36:18 UTC +00:00]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `updated_at` values? Do you have any NULLs in the database? Have you checked `Post.all` in chunks to find which records are causing the problem?

Comment: Yes I have already checked. The thing is that this is happening in different models, whenever I try to add more than one updated_at time.
I have added the array contents which, in fact, are not DateTime but Time. I read somewhere that created_at and updated_at where returning ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone classes, but I get Times.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you summing timestamps at all? Looks like you're using it as part of a cache key but a sum isn't going to guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try making the cache key just the most recently updated post?

```
<% cache [:posts, :index, @posts.order(:updated_at).last] do %>
```